# Not able to load the third party dll in IIS hosted rest WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, dll, dllimport

I have hosted a `Rest WCF` to my `IIS 7`. I tested the everything and it works fine except to importing the `dll`. My instance class code are following:

```
[OperationContract, WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/getname?name={name}&age={age}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    bool getname(string name, string age);

[OperationContract, WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/getcallfromdll?name={name}&age={age}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    bool getcallfromdll(string name, string age);
```

Whereas the definition of above methods are :

```
public string getname(string name, int len)
    {
        return "It's working";
    }
public string getcallfromdll(string name, int len)
    {
        return UnsafeNativeMethods.getvalue(name, len); //Unsafe.. is a internal structure
    }

internal static class UnsafeNativeMethods
    {
        const string _dllLocation = "school.dll";

        [DllImport(_dllLocation, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern bool getvalue(string name, String len);
     }
```

When  tried to run `localhost:8085/service.svc/getname?name=kajn&len=21`: it returns `"It's working"`, which is correct but whenever i tried to call `localhost:8085/service.svc/getcallfromdll?name=kajn&len=21`: It returns `The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details.`

I searched for it and somehow i got to know that it all happening due to service are not bale to find the `DLL`. To solve this i tried to put my dll in following places but it didn't help me:( :

- system32/inetsrv
- SysWOW64/inetsrv
- in bin folder
- i also put the same folder where the project exists.

But nothing works for me. Please suggest me a solution.

NOTE: there are no problem with the dll because i call the dll methods from a self hosted WCF application and it was working perfectly. At that time i put my dll into `bin/debug` folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that it could be related to the fact that IIS may copy binaries to shadow location and when it does that it may not realize the unmanaged dll may be required. Is your "school.dll" part of your WCF solution and is it added as an reference? Also does it depend on any other unmanaged dlls? Next time you get that error you can try to search your system to find all instances of your WCF dll, then if you find one in shadow location, take a look if your "school.dll" is there too.

Comment: No i can't add `school.dll` as a reference, because it is a `native dll` created by myself. No, it does not depend on another dll. I am not able to understand you. If you don't mind then please explain it little bit more

Comment: Yes, sorry, I wasn't very precise. I usually add unmanaged dll to the project file, as a normal item and the specify under "Copy to Output Directory" value of "Copy Always". Few other suggestions - If you have 32bit dll, in IIS under application pool try setting "Enable 32ibt applications" to true. You could also try running your application in debugger, so that you can see what exactly error message you are getting.

Comment: P.S. I actually fired up a VS and created very similar scenario as yours, so I am positive it is possible :)

Comment: Thanks @sebastian. you helped me twice on stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you should turn on WCF Tracing on the server and see what the actual error/exception is. But I would suspect some sort of permissions-related error... i.e. the DLL can be found, but the IIS worker process doesn't have the right permissions to read it or to execute methods in it. Just for debugging purposes, try setting the permission on the DLL such that it can be read/executed by "Everyone".